# Transition chaining and cancellation

Tags: animation, d3.js, transition

I have two functions that perform animations on lines. The first function, `one` is executed at the beginning, in order to perform operations on the enter selection, and only animates the lines' horizontal movement (`x1` and `x2`). The second function `two` only animates the lines' height (only `y2`,`y1` stays fixed).

Through user events, function `one` cannot be interrupted by function `two`, but vice versa (also because the animation in `two` is considerably longer). This means that, when the transition from `two` is still running, the user can trigger `one`.

This gave me serious headaches, because `one` would somehow take the values of the last state of the running transition of `two` instead of correctly assigning a data-driven value (i.e. `.attr('y2', function(d){ ... });`).

http://jsfiddle.net/h39WN/6/ - Please do the following: Click on `one`. You see that only the horizontal movement is animated as the data changes. You also see that at the end of its execution, the lines should always be ordered from lowest to highest. 
Click on `two` once and wait the full 2 seconds until its animation is completed. Then click on `one` again. This is the desired behavior.

Now click on `two`, wait a few ms and then click on `one` - you see that the lines keep the height of the last state of `two`'s animation, even though they are correctly ordered. (I know the data are not realistic and maybe a bit confusing in this example, but they still allow to replicate the problem).

I then came up with the solution to schedule another, "empty", transition on the lines in `one` - according to the docs this should cancel the one still running in `two` when `one` is invoked:

```
var one = function () {

    var svg = d3.select('svg');

    vis.mobileTeams = svg
        .selectAll('.teamGroup')
        .data(data.values, function (d) {
            return d.ID;
        });

    // ENTER
    var teamEnter = vis.mobileTeams
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'teamGroup');
    // enter line
    teamEnter
        .append('line')
        .attr('class', 'teamWeightedLine');


    // UPDATE THE LINE
    // HEIGHT - SHOULD NOT BE ANIMATED
    svg
        .selectAll('.teamGroup line')
        .attr('y1', paddingY)

    // I inserted a transition here to cancel 
    // the one triggered by the other function
    var lineTransition = svg
        .selectAll('.teamGroup line')
        .transition()
        .attr('y2', function(d){ ... });

    // I need to use transition chaining so changing 'y2' 
    // with a transition does not get 
    // overwritten by the following transition

    // HORIZONTAL POSITION - SHOULD BE ANIMATED
    lineTransition
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
    // 'x1' and 'x2' are the only values that 
    // need to be animated in this function
        .attr('x1', function (d) {
            return function(d){ ... });
        })
        .attr('x2', function (d) {
            return function(d){ ... });
        });
};
```

And here is the second function.

```
var two = function () {
    var svg = d3.select('svg');

    // this is where the only transition concerning HEIGHT is supposed to take place
    svg
        .selectAll('.teamGroup line')
        .transition()
        .ease('circle-out')
        .duration(2000)
        .attr('y2', vis.mobileCalculateScoreToHeight);
    console.log('mobile vis updated');
};
```

Even though this fixes the "interference" problem as `two`'s transition is canceled because another one is scheduled, it brings another problem:

```
var lineTransition = svg
            .selectAll('.teamGroup line')
            .transition()
            .attr('y2', function(d){ ... });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/96uN6/8/ This is the fiddle that incorporates this change. Even when `two` is interrupted by `one`, do the correct heights result in the end - but:

`y2` is now being animated in `one` too! I know that `.transition()` brings with it a default duration of 250ms, so I did this:

```
var lineTransition = svg
            .selectAll('.teamGroup line')
            .transition()
            .duration(0)
            .attr('y2', function(d){ ... });
```

This, in turn, brings another problem: `y2` is not set at all now, i.e. the `<line>`s don't even have it as an attribute:

Weirdly, it works when using a very short duration (so the animation is barely visible), but it only works sometimes and is probably browser-dependent:

```
var lineTransition = svg
            .selectAll('.teamGroup line')
            .transition()
            .duration(10)
            .attr('y2', function(d){ ... });
```

Setting `y2` in the regular selection instead of the transition selection does not work either as it brings back the "interference" problem - as `y2` is set when the animation from `two` is still running.

```
svg
    .selectAll('.teamGroup line')
    .attr('y1', paddingY)
    .attr('y2', function(d){ ... });

var lineTransition = svg
    .selectAll('.teamGroup line')
    .transition();
```

The approach without transition chaining does not work either, of course, because the first transition is immediately canceled by the second and `y2` is never set.

```
svg
        .selectAll('.teamGroup line')
        .transition()
        .duration(10)
        .attr('y2', function(d){ ... });

    svg
        .selectAll('.teamGroup line')
        .transition()
        .duration(TRANSDURATION)
        .attr('x1', function (d) {
            return function(d){ ... };
        })
        .attr('x2', function (d) {
            return function(d){ ... };
        });
```

So the only possible solution working for me (the one with the short duration) seems very quirky, there must be a better solution, mustn't it? 
Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

Comment: I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around this -- could you perhaps make a small example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I added fiddles which hopefully explain what is happening - it was quite hard as I could not use the existing infrastructure of my application, i.e. the real data, but anyway, feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This behaviour is pretty much by design and I don't think there's a good way of doing what you want with the current version of D3 -- ideally, you'd need an "interrupted" transition event (which may not even be that hard to implement, but require modifications to the source code). Would it be acceptable in your application to combine both transitions in one function to eliminate this problem, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/h39WN/7/ (just click on "one")?

Comment: No, I need the two functions, because the latter is triggered whenever the user sets a value, i.e. the data are scaled according to a value the user specifies with a handle that can be dragged, whereas the second is invoked when pushing a button, which is handled by `one` - two different actions, two different data manipulations. Mhh. But why can't I set `.duration(0)`? Or, in other words, why does this work sometimes and sometimes not?

Comment: Not sure if this is right solution for your problem but you can disable button "two" while function "one" is running. Here is example - http://jsfiddle.net/cuckovic/e9eu8/

Comment: I know, but this has nothing to do with the problem. And I need both buttons to be clickable all the time because it would be annoying if the user had to wait for the end of the animation all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through Mike Bostock (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1877), I found out that I can use `selection.interrupt()` to cancel any previous transitions, i.e., already running transitions.

So, the quirky

```
var lineTransition = svg
            .selectAll('.teamGroup line')
            .transition()
            .duration(0)
            .attr('y2', function(d){ ... });
```

becomes

```
var lineTransition = svg
            .selectAll('.teamGroup line')
            .interrupt()
            .attr('y2', function(d){ ... });
```

It's as easy as that.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/96uN6/9/

Comment: That is nice solution but you still get messy lines if user clicks "two" before "one" animation is finished.

Comment: Sure, you would need to adapt the code in the same way when both use cases should be possible.